# Python not working in command line (Windows 10); already changed PATH system variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-10

The path is:

`C:\Python27;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PharosSystems\Core;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;`

Comment: Try using the [Windows installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2714/). Be sure to get the right version (32-bit Windows x86 MSI installer or 64-bit Windows x86-64 MSI installer). They will offer to change your `PATH` for you if you wish.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @martineau, that worked!

Comment: `C:\Python27` is clearly there.

Comment: Are you showing  `PATH` from the CMD shell in which you were trying to run python.exe? Or did you copy it from the system environment variables editor? Modifying this value in the registry won't magically reach into existing processes to change their environment. Every process has its own private copy of environment variables inherited from or set by the parent process. The environment variable editor broadcasts a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message that causes Explorer to reload its environment. After that, restarting CMD from Explorer wil inherit the new value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're trying to do a fresh install of Python?

My suggestion is if you're trying to install python 2 go with python x,y as it comes with a lot of things pre-installed and it's much easier to get up and running:
https://python-xy.github.io/

If you're trying to install python 3 I recommend going with python anaconda:

https://www.anaconda.com/download/

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I already have Python installed. The folder is C:\Python27

Comment: Anaconda also has python2 support

Comment: @manofbear you have it installed but you're struggling with having it in the path and probably things like pip install will also be broken. If you just install one of the above options during the install process it will add everything to PATH automatically. It makes your life much simpler, but upto you.
Edit: reading your updates sounds like it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Following @martineau 's suggestion, I reinstalled Python and checked the option to add Python to path during installation. Python then ran from command prompt with no problem.

Checked the system path - C:\Python27\ was added. Apparently this second backslash is essential; I already had C:\Python27 and this didn't work.

Path after reinstalling:

C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PharosSystems\Core;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;

Comment: No, the second backslash is redundant. Remove the redundant "C:\Python27" entry from your path.